# liner operation (Matrix Determinant)

Tags: linear-algebra

I was reading the following article http://betterexplained.com/articles/linear-algebra-guide/ and I have a doubt in the beginning of the article, sorry for my ignorance. My Question is with this part of the article:

An operation is a calculation based on some inputs. Which operations are linear and predictable? Multiplication, it seems.

Exponents $(F(x) = x^2)$ aren’t predictable: $10^2$ is 100, but $20^2$ is 400. We doubled the input but quadrupled the output.

Surprisingly, regular addition isn’t linear either. Consider the “add three” function:

\begin{align*}
F(x) &= x + 3 \\
F(10) &= 13 \\
F(20) &= 23
\end{align*}

We doubled the input and did not double the output.

Our only hope is to multiply by a constant: $F(x) = ax$ (in our roof example, $a=1/3$). However, we can still combine linear operations to make a new linear operation:**(This is the part I don't understand)**

$G(x, y, z) = F(x + y + z) = F(x) + F(y) + F(z)$

G is made of 3 linear subpieces: if we double the inputs, we’ll double the output.

We have “mini arithmetic”: multiply inputs by a constant, and add the results. It’s actually useful because we can split inputs apart, analyze them individually, and combine the results:

$G(x,y,z) = G(x,0,0) + G(0,y,0) + G(0,0,z)$

If the inputs interacted like exponents, we couldn’t separate them — we’d have to analyze everything at once.

My question is why $G(x,y,z) = F(x+y+z)$ or what is he trying to explain because I got lost in that part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that he earlier defined $F(x)=ax$? Then, if you take the variable of $F$ to be $x+y+z$, you would get $F(x+y+z)=a(x+y+z)=ax+ay+az$ which is the same as $F(x)+F(y)+F(z).$

To say that $G(x,y,z)$ is the same as $F(x+y+z)$ isn't *wrong* but it is perhaps not the best idea to approach the subject matter this way, in my opinion. Here's why: 
The author is trying to introduce how a vector works and is saying that it is something that behaves the same way as a function like $G$. However, a vector that takes the three variables $x,y,z$ (as its basis, but never mind; that comes later!) can effectively write out $ax+by+cz$ for any $a,b,c$ and doesn't have to multiply only with one constant $a$. So keep that in mind.

If it still doesn't make sense, let me know in the comments below and I'll elaborate.

Comment: Oh, I see I didn't see that he was defining $F(x)=ax$ thank you so much for clarifying that to me. So that means that he is defining $G(x,y,z)$ as a function in the form $ax + ay + az$?

Comment: @kprincipe Exactly :)